# How to access already running instance of a class without creating an actual object

Tags: java, multithreading, class, instance, runnable

I have a problem with Java GUI. It is hard to explain but I will do my best. I have 2 GUI classes one is class I and other is class G. Class I is initiated from main method. In the class I there is a field (instance of) class G. Reason being that class I collects vital information and passes it to instance of class G. When a button pressed in class I, that sets the class I frame visibility to false and instance of class G to true (showing up the G interface). Problem here is that I want to be able to make a listener in G that sets visibility of I back to true thus displaying the previously edited window. I had a solution of disposing of all frames and creating a new instance but that only shows a new cleared instance of I. Here are some code snippets:

Class I:

Fields:

```
private JFileChooser j;
private FileFilter filter;
private GUI g;  //<--- it is initialized shortly after.
private Font masterFont;
private JFrame frame;
private JButton done;

private JButton browse1;
private JButton browse2;.....
```

Sets G visible and I invisible:

```
class Done implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

        g.setArray(array);
        System.out.println(array);
        setText();
        frame.setVisible(false);
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.setVisible2(false);
        if (g.clear.isSelected()) {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }


    }
```

Class G: Note, here I cannot make an instance of I because I keep getting Stack Overflow error.

Hard Reset: This one just creates new instance while disposing the rest (possibly wasteful because the old instance of I is not properly closed)

```
private class Reset implements ActionListener {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            frame.dispose();
            frame2.dispose();

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
            public void run() {
                Intro g = new Intro();
                g.setVisible(true);

            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access the "already running" instance of I without creating any new ones.

Comment: take a look at the static keyword ;)

Comment: Pass `this` in a setter method to the other class. Whatever you do, don't use static as @Hiro2k recommends.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thank you so much. I did not realize fully what "this" keyword really meant or did but now I do. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current top level window from the ActionEvent object that is passed into your ActionListener's actionPerformed method. Get the source object that caused the listener to be called via `getSource()` and then call the `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor()` on the source to obtain the Window (JFrame, JDialog, or whatever it may be).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to "I" to "G" (via constructor or setter) and use it in `actionPerformed` to set the visibility to true.  If you only ever have a single instance of "I" another approach is create a static reference to it that you can reference from "G".

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be for class G to hold a reference to I.

```
public class G
{
    private I i;
    // ... other stuff

    public G(I i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

And when necessary hide itself and show the "I" GUI window (or whatever it is). I would go for this solution if class "I" is a parent of (owns) "G" (which seems to be the case from the code you've posted). You are the one who can best determine if this is the case, but a simple example is if you have a main window and some dialog window (which would act as the child in this case). If they are both equal citizens (both are owned by some third class), I would pass a reference to that class instead and have it manage when "I" and "G" are shown or hidden.

Another solution is to use the singleton design pattern if you're sure that you only ever need 1 instance of the class. I don't have enough experience with it to say if it's necessarily good or bad, but I've seen a lot of negativity towards this design pattern, so use with caution.